# Invalid Developer's Key in Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-drive-api

Im researching about some custom google API and in the site it seems to be running okay. im able to upload the desired file to my own drive account, but when i tried it to my local environment its not working. i already changed the developer's key. the oauth seems to be okay but the developer's key might have a problem. here is the demo that the guy provided. https://howdy39.github.io/google-picker-api-demo/ but when i tried it to my local environment its not working, any of them. here is a sample  picture of the problem[image: Error Message] This happens after the login screen so the auth keys are okay. i dont know what to do with the developer's key. here is the original source code provided. https://github.com/howdy39/google-picker-api-demo/blob/master/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `Credentials - API key - Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)`.

Try adding `localhost`.

[image]